# iPad: Show a help popup window?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How do I show a help popup window on the iPad?  I want to show a modal popup window that grays out the background similar to the email applications "Compose New Mail" app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the various values you can set for modalPresentationStyle on UiViewController.

Comment: Do you also have to set the view you are popping up to be a different kind of view?